# promise-tracker in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, promise, tracker

I have problems when using promise-tracker.

What I want is to track a conversation. And part of my code is following:

js:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ajoslin.promise-tracker'])
  .factory('Conversation', function (promiseTracker) {
    return {
      addMessage: function (opts) {
        /* Post data to server */
        var promise = POSTING DATA;
        promiseTracker('message').addPromise(promise);
      },
      removeMessage: function (opts) {
        /* Delete data */
      }
    }
  })

  .directive('newMessage', function (Conversation) {
    return {
      scope: true,
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function (scope) {
        scope.addMessage = function () {
          Conversation.addMessage( { /* Some opts */ } )
        }
      }
    }
  })

  .directive('Tracker', function (promiseTracker) {
    var opts = { /* Spinner opts */  }
    return {
      scope: true,
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'EA',
      templateUrl: 'tracker.html',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        /* new spinner */
        scope.tracker = promiseTracker(attrs.tracker);
        /* And some thing */
      }
    }
  })
```

---

new-message.html:

```
<form name="myForm" new-message>
    <input type="text" name="content" />
    <i tracker="message" ></i>
</form>
```

tracker.html:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <i ng-show="tracker.active()" ng-show="!isHidden"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" ng-click="addMessage()" ng-disabled="tracker.active()">
</div>
```

---

With these code, It works well when there is ONLY ONE form in the page.

BUT when I add more form in the template, it has some problems.

When tracking a promise, all spinner show!

[now result(click)](http://i1361.photobucket.com/albums/r678/scarlexs/result_zps9bee4091.png?t=1373714073)

And this is what I want:

[hope result(click)](http://i1361.photobucket.com/albums/r678/scarlexs/want_zps06b98ca4.png?t=1373714067)

I suppose that there is something wrong in my scope. But I don't know how to fix it.

Can anyone help me?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You want a global scope promise tracker if you want to display a loading spinner graphic for your app--an example lifted directly from the official docs:

```
angular.module('app', ['ajoslin.promise-tracker'])

.factory('myTracker', function (promiseTracker) {
  return promiseTracker();
})

.controller('AppCtrl', function ($rootScope, myTracker) {
  $rootScope.$watch(myTracker.active, function (isActive) {
    //doSomething()
  });
});
```